# TransactionScope With Files In C#

Tags: c#, file, transactions, scope, transactionscope

I've been using TransactionScope to work with the database and it feels nice. What I'm looking for is the following:

```
using(var scope=new TransactionScope())
{               
    // Do something with a few files...
    scope.Complete();
}
```

but obviously this doesn't work -- if there are 20 files, and an exception occurs on the 9th file, all previous 8 remain *changed* and the rest *unchanged* -- no rollback is performed. So, what would be the best way to implement a scope-like behavior for files?

I'm hoping there is a simple answer, but if not, could you just give me a few pointers, or point me to an related article?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [Transactional NTFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363764%28VS.85%29.aspx), introduced by Windows Vista.

[Here is a managed wrapper](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=transactionalfilemgr).

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, their managed wrapper wraps each function in a transaction scope of its own.  I had to create overloads which allowed me to pass in my own scope.

Comment: Just FYI, Microsoft is considering deprecating Transactional NTFS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: And they have now provided the [Alternatives to using Transactional NTFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh802690(v=vs.85).aspx) page on MSDN, although after reading that page, I have to say that it's *not* much of an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the [.NET Transactional File Manager](https://transactionalfilemgr.codeplex.com/) library available on Codeplex and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TxFileManager). It supports any file system and is not a wrapper over Transactional NTFS.

From the project description:

> Transactional File Manager is a .NET API that supports including file
>   system operations such as file copy, move, delete, append, etc. in a
>   transaction. It's an implementation of
>   System.Transaction.IEnlistmentNotification (works with
>   System.Transactions.TransactionScope).

Comment: Thanks, @ErwinMayer. For whatever reason, the github and nuget versions of the Tx File Manager library are different: the github one includes `File.WriteAllBytes` and the nuget one doesn't. You can get the github version here: https://github.com/rsevil/Transactions